# Communication between two scripts

Tags: php, python, communication

i'm creating embedded system with infinite Python script (launched on startup) and PHP web page. PHP web page have to communicate with that script.

**Current solution** is file based communication. PHP writes to file some command and Python writes response to some other (or same) file.

**Another possible solution** is to call some NOT infinite Python script only at need with PHP `$response = shell_exec('./script.py');`

Both solutions are possible but they are complicated and I need that Python script to be infinite.

Is there any way how to open some communication tunnel between two independents scipts on same linux device?

Like UART, telnet, etc. between two devices.

Now i'm searching for solution with PHP-PYTHON and PYTHON-PYTHON communication but sometimes i need this for example with Bash, TCL, etc.

Thank you (and sorry for not good english)

Radim

Comment: May i suggest basing your code on one server side language or is there a reason for using two different languages?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Comment: WebSockets might help you?

Comment: I need this for real hardware device box in my hands. Python script manage IO pins a PHP show some informations about it. So can't do it with one script. Thanks for Inter-process_communication a WebSockets. I will look on it.

Comment: Maybe I will try file in RAM. So i will still use file based commincation but that file will be at RAM. With classic file based i was afraid of destroying flash memory with too many writes.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing much about what you are trying to achieve, i would go for a base http solution, starting a simple http server with python

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()

.... do something with the http request and send the response
```

Then the php script can simply make some GET/POST/etc.. request to python directly, and grab the http responses, for example via cURL:

```
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "localhost");

// set port
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8000);

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Of course this is a simple stub and it should be tweaked a bit, but it should give you a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for example. But again it is little bit complicated. And that port will be opened for everyone else who has conection to my device, isnt it?

Comment: Well you should bind the http server to localhost, and put the port behind a firewall (filtering non-localhost connection), then only requests forwarded by your own host should be served